# switch store view with href

Tags: magento, view, switch-statement, store

I'm trying to switch magento store views by url/href.

I created a default store view, with a cms where a block gets loaded
which contains a landing page where you should choose your language. After
it is chosen it appends the language code to the url and sets a cookie.

I created a second store view, with the base url http://myshop.dev/en/.
So if the user has chosen "England" he gets redirected to http://myshop.dev/en/, but the
english shop doesn't get called.
Instead the message appears "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found."

I'm quite new to magento.

Answer (score 0):

Not very well worded, but sounds like you just want to create a store switcher drop down.

If so, have a look in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml for an example.